# AppFabric CallBack

Tags: caching, appfabric

I am using Windows AppFabric Caching service in my ASP.Net 4.0 C# application. I need to use this for my shopping cart. As inventory items are limited in stock so I want that a user must complete the transaction with in 10 minutes so that other users get the quantity updates in real time. My problem is I am not sure how to update my cache if user doesn't complete the transaction with in stipulated time. Is there any thing called CallBack notification so that I could get to know that cache has timed out and I can update values on other cache.

Please help.

Thanks 
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

you can do many things here.

a) Set the cache values to time out after 10 minuttes.
b) Enhance the tiemout setup with notifications.

If you expose your inventory stats with a RESTful web service, you can put a lot of this logic in the service layer, and keep your web app (and possibly mobile apps) more simple.